# On clicking a button on a web page, can a dynamic link be generated? can we navigate webpage to the dynamically generated link

Tags: php, javascript

I am new to PHP and javascript programming 
I have a string that can be "abc" or "aac" or "aaa" etc based on the inputs given by the user.  After the user clicks some button(say submit) I want to generate a dynamic link like www.domain.com/abc or www.domain.com/aac based on string and navigate the user to the generated link. Is this possible? 
Thank You

Comment: Do you have any experience with mod_rewrite? This allows say www.domain.com/abc to be interpreted as www.domain.com/handle.php?link=abc.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But StackOverflow expect people who ask questions to show research efforts. Since it is not your case, you're unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: @EtienneMiret and now there're 5 answers...

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos Yes, I've seen that. It seems that people here are nicer than I though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually define a function and set it your form action. Then taking the user input it will be really each in the function to use `header('location:YOUR_SITE_URL/'.$_GET['user_input']); die;` for redirecting the user to desired url.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, using routing. A real world example is how your usernames get to be part of the URL in social sites like Facebook.

What you need is a database of some sort to store the string, and it's matched data (could be an ID, or some identified) to tell the server what to load when that string is received. You'd also need routing code, which parses the entire url in search of that certain segment which should contain the string. This is how routing works in frameworks like CodeIgniter, Connect and Express.

In JS, routers in Connect look like:

```
app.route('/users/:username',function(username){
  //okay! we got the username!
  //now we'll look for it in the database if it's there
});
```

For PHP, [here's an article](http://www.codekites.com/parse-mvc-style-urls-in-php/) regarding URL parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can pass the string variable throw POST or GET when the user click submit
and then echo the link you want with the string congrenated. assuming you want to use php take a look at the example

```
$adress = "www.domain.com/";

$string = $_POST["get_string"];

$result = $adress + $string; 



echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP :

Use  methode in your page and store the variable to $UrlName (for example)

and continued with

```
echo("<script>location.href = \"www.domain.com/" . $UrlName . "\";</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

First in `page1.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php" >
String: <input type="text" name="string" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in `page2.php`:

```
header('location:www.domain.com/string/'.$_POST['string']);
```

But you should put a `.htaccess` containing:

```
Redirect /string/(.+) /page3.php?string=$1 [B,QSA]
```

And `page4.php`:

```
echo $_GET['string'];
```